# Emit baking details results in a weird projection

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

Here is the emission details im trying to project:
[image]

Onto this mesh, which is the same thing but with a tail, among some sculpting that smooths the transitions between the ears and the tail:
[image]
The problem is that when i project the details, I get something odd. It looks like its projecting in multple directions? I say this because I can see the "eyes" details multiple times, but not in the right place. The normals and sizes of all objects here are correct.
Heres what the details look like:
[image]

[image]

If anyone could tell me whats happening that would be great. I will gladly post more info if needed.

Comment: If you've unwrapped with the Project from View method you'll also have the back faces unwrapped and overlapping with the front faces, so they will also receive the image, you could re-unwrap them and put them where you want on the image

Comment: I havent projected from view, they all have their own UV maps that I unwrapped with my own seams, and I dont see any additional UV maps it could be taking from.  Is there any place else where this type of data is stored other than the object data properties?

Comment: You need to correctly place the UVs in the UV Editor, so open the UV Editor, select the faces of the object and check if they are correctly placed in the UV Editor, if not just move them

Comment: https://gyazo.com/c8140b29423b6da56a1b52b0233f515a https://gyazo.com/13d25e1b24dbe4722823b7a59811e17d Here are both my UVs, you can see one of them is mirrored, so the symmetrical sides overlap. Would that be the issue?

Comment: If on the back of your object you don't see what you're supposed to see it's because the UV faces are not correctly placed but it's hard to guess from your screenshots